# Is math independent of our sensory experience?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics, critique-of-pure-reason

I've been asking myself this and other questions in the field of philosophy of mathematics. Could we, if we were isolated from any kind of sensory experience, be able to learn mathematics?

This question has been moved from the math SE to the Philosophy SE.

Comment: The most well known researcher in this field is Stanislas Dehaene, he writes quite well.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is completely off-topic. After all, philosophers like Kant wrote on the nature of mathematical thought. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert, hopefully someone else feels up to the task. I do agree though that the second question, namely what it takes to learn math, is off-topic here. Maybe we can agree to delete that part and focus on the first?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. I'll take back my close vote.

Comment: @iphigenie I'll erase that part then. This same questions was put on hold in the math SE, and I don't know where else should I ask it.

Comment: @Miguelgondu Regarding the deleted part, I would try http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: perhaps you could could be more specific with the stipulation "if we were isolated from any kind of sensory experience".

Comment: In general, about the problem of the "sensational" origin of knowledge, tou can see in *SEP * [Étienne Bonnot de Condillac](Étienne Bonnot de Condillac) and [Hermann von Helmholtz](http://plato.stanford.edu//entries/hermann-helmholtz/), but with very limited reference to the problem of mathematics. It may be of interest also [Ernst Mach](http://plato.stanford.edu//entries/ernst-mach/) and his *Space and Geometry in the Light of Physiological, Psychological and Physical Inquiry* (ed or 1906 - Dover reprint).

Comment: In addition to Stanislas Dehaene, [*The Number Sense: How the Mind Creates Mathematics*](http://www.amazon.com/The-Number-Sense-Creates-Mathematics/dp/0199753873/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1397504087&sr=8-3&keywords=Stanislas+Dehaene) you can see also : Heike Wiese, [*Numbers Language and the Human Mind*](http://www.amazon.com/Numbers-Language-Human-Heike-Wiese/dp/0521108659/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397504146&sr=8-1&keywords=Heike+Wiese+Numbers+Language+and+the+Human+Mind) (2003).

Comment: Also : Marcus Giaquinto, [*Visual Thinking in Mathematics*](http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Thinking-Mathematics-Marcus-Giaquinto/dp/0199575533/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397504192&sr=8-1&keywords=Marcus+Giaquinto+Visual+Thinking+in+Mathematics) (2007).

Comment: You misunderstood yourself. There is NO place in the universe and inside your soul where there is no information. Think about it. Hard.

Comment: A last sugegstion : Philip J. Davis, [*Mathematics and Common Sense : A Case of Creative Tension*](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Common-Sense-Creative-Tension/dp/1568812701/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397564844&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=PhilipJ+Davis+Mathematics+and+Common+Sense) (2006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is math independent of our sensory experience?

Kants answer, in a sense, is that it is both dependent on sensory experience and also not. He claims that our intuition for space, through which we construct geometry, is *a priori* and thus independent of experience, but also *synthetic*, so that it is more than the rules of logic; he says that this is possible because our intuition for space is a neccessary condition to have any experience at all.

Frege, agreed with this for mathematics considered solely as geometry, but disputed arithmetic fits into what he calls Kants *psychologism*, perhaps a term that he picked up from Hume. Frege is a key figure in the early 20 Century project to reduce arithmetic to logic; and it is this thought that bypasses Kant, or so one supposes, because this would mean that arithmetic being solely based on logic cannot be *synthetic*, but must be *analytic*.

> Could we, if we were isolated from any kind of sensory experience, be able to learn mathematics?

Thus, Kants answer is no for both arithmetic and geometry; and Frege says yes for arithmetic, and no for geometry.

As for *learning* mathematics - The SEP says on the [Kantian philosophy of mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-mathematics/#KanTheConMatConDisPurReaDogUse):

> In a series of papers, Charles Parsons has argued that the syntheticity of mathematical judgments depends on mathematical intuitions being fundamentally immediate, and he explains the immediacy of such representations in a perceptual way, as a direct, phenomenological presence to the mind.

That is the abstract '2' as distinct from, say a concrete '2 bottles' or '2 books' that we might look at and perceive, is *not* abstract to our sensibility, it has a 'phenomenological' presence.

The hard work of *learning* mathematics is to synthesise these concepts so that the abstract concept has this actual sensual presence in the mind. One might say the moment of 'clarity' or 'illumination' is a spark given of by this act of mental synthesis. This is the beginning, the process and becoming of the mathematical Subject - subject as in subjectivity, not as in topic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question would be no.

Sensory inputs are the only mechanism for input into the brain aside from evolutionary 'pre-programmed' instincts.

Without input there would be very little our instinctive 'lizard brain' could do. Our cerebral cortex wouldn't have a whole lot of information in it to do anything.

Think about this. If we take a newborn baby and restrict all sensory inputs (use your imagination because restricting all inputs would probably not be possible without essentially rendering it dead or a vegitable). This child can not formulate any new thoughts because it would have nothing to cause this to occur. No senses means nothing changes. Nothing to react to, nothing to think about.

If we assume however that we were given a certain amount of knowledge prior to cutting off our sensory inputs, it may be possible to conceptualize mathematics based on thought and contemplation over the existing intelligence we had already obtained. Simply thinking about our fingers and toes for example could spawn the beginning of mathmatics

Comment: Have you heard of _Genie_, the _wild child_?, I'll leave you a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmdycJQi4QA)

Comment: I think that this is exactly the part of the question that doesn't belong here. The sensory development of children is not a philosophical answer to the a priori-ness of mathematical thought. Not that I disagree with what you've said. I just think that this would rather belong on cogsci than there.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suppose if you take Plato's [theory of Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory%5fof%5fForms) as the starting point, then you could say that abstract mathematical concepts are merely examples of Forms and therefore exist independent of our sensory experience.
2. On the other hand, the direct answer to your question ( are we "able to learn mathematics" if we had no senses) has to be "no." We are unable to accumulate any knowledge without senses. This isn't really a philosophical question as a scientific one - a human brain is a mesh of neuron connections that get formed over time based on input. Without input, neurons wouldn't train themselves to connect in new ways that lead to our accumulation of knowledge.